# How do I center this slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I'm using A11Y Slider to do a slider in a project. I'm almost finishing the project but I got stuck in this part. I've tried to fix it by centering it using `margin-inline:auto, scroll-snap-align:center` but both attempts failed.
My thoughts are that I hard coded something in the code that prevents me from centering it correctly with the button. I've been on this for hours and I stopped adding code in order to not get too messy.
Thank you all for the help.
[This is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXIE9.png) and
[this is what it should be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctP0i.png)
All of my JavaScript, CSS and HTML:

```js
const slider = new A11YSlider(document.querySelector('.slider'), {
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    dots: true,
    centerMode:true,
    arrows:false,
    responsive: {
        480: {
          dots: false // dots enabled 1280px and up
        }
      }
  });
```

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--size-600);
  list-style: none;
}

.a11y-slider-container{
  margin-block: var(--size-700);
  margin-inline: var(--size-400);
}

.slider > * {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width:30em){
  .slider{
    scroll-padding-inline: 25px;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
  .slider > *{
    width: 50%;
  }
  .a11y-slider-container{
    margin-inline: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width:50em){
  .slider > *{
    width: 33%;
  }
}

.slider-content{
  border-radius: var(--size-100);
  padding: var(--size-700) var(--size-600);
  background: var(--color-neutral-200);
}

.slider img{
  width: var(--size-800);
  position: relative;
  margin-inline: auto;
  top: calc(var(--size-800)/2);
}

.a11y-slider-dots{
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--size-300);
  margin-block: var(--size-500);
  justify-content: center;
}

.a11y-slider-dots li{
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.a11y-slider-dots li button{
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-accent-400) !important;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.a11y-slider-dots li button.active{
  background: var(--color-accent-400);
}

.padding-block-700{
  padding-block: var(--size-700);
}

.text-center{
  text-align: center;
}

.font-size-secondary-heading {
  font-size: var(--font-size-secondary-heading);
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-bold);
}

.flow *+*{
  margin-top: var(--flow-spacer, 3em);
}

.button{
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
  padding: 1.25em 2.5em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-bold);
  font-size: var(--font-size-button);
  color: var(--color-neutral-100);
  background-color: var(--color-accent-400);
  box-shadow: 0 1.1em 1em -1em var(--color-accent-500);
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus-visible{
  background-color: var(--color-accent-300);
}
```

```html
      <section class="carousel | padding-block-700  text-center">
        <h2 class="font-size-secondary-heading font-weight-bold">
          What they've said
        </h2>
        <!-- Carousel here-->
        <ul class="slider">
          <li>
            <img src="images/avatar-anisha.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider-content | flow" style="--flow-spacer:1rem">
              <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Anisha Li</h3>
              <p>"Manage has supercharged our team's workflow. The ability to maintain visibility on larger milestones at all times keeps everyone motivated."</p>
           </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/avatar-ali.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider-content | flow" style="--flow-spacer:1rem">
              <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Ali Bravo</h3>
              <p data-width="wide">"We have been able to cancel so many other subscriptions since using Manage. There is no more cross-channel confusion and everyone is much more focused."</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/avatar-richard.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider-content | flow" style="--flow-spacer:1rem">
              <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Richard Watts</h3>
              <p>"Manage allows us to provide structure and process. It keeps us organized and focused. I can't stop recommending them to everyone I talk to!"</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/avatar-shanai.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider-content | flow" style="--flow-spacer:1rem">
              <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Shanai Gough</h3>
              <p>"Their software allows us to track, manage and collaborate on our project from anywhere. It keeps the whole team in-sync without being intrusive."</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="button">Get Started</button>
      </section>
```